# how do I create a string with an escaped open parens?

Tags: javascript, string

consider the following

```
➜ ~ node
Welcome to Node.js v16.15.1.
Type ".help" for more information.
> s = '('
'('
> s = '\('
'('
> s = '\\('
'\\('
> s = String.raw`(`
'('
> s = String.raw`\(`
'\\('
> s = String.raw`\\(`
'\\\\('
```

So, how do I set `s` to `'\('`?

Comment: You're messing up "value" with "representation"

Comment: I am trying to build a complicated regexp pattern in which I need to represent escaped open and close parens. I want use a variable to hold these values so I can change them at will. But I can't get the single backslash escaped parens. Hope that explains why

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't.

You're confused about the *value* of a string and its *representation* (whence Python `repr()` function).

A parenthesis is not a special character in a JavaScript string, so it will *never* be escaped in its canonical "code" representation. Therefore you will never make a string whose representation is `'\('`.

If you mean a string of length 2, with the first character being a backslash, and the second one being a left parenthesis, then `'\\('` is what you want.

Comment: let's say I want a regexp to match "foo(bar)". I set `s1 = "foo"`, `s2 = "\("`, `s3 = "bar"`, and `s4 = "\)"` so I can make <code>re = `${s1}${s2}${s3}${s4}`</code>. How do I do that? (this is a contrived example)

Comment: @punkish `re = s1+s2+s3+s4` is enough. Then you can use `new Regexp(re)`.